grub_file_filters not found
I wanted to turn off my touchpad on a Dell M4700.  I turned it off in settings but it didn't work.  I found that sudo input set-prop 16 "Device Enabled" 0 worked.  So all I did was add it in a script file ./touchpad-off.sh to my .profile to change it at startup. When I rebooted I got a black screen, it just sat there.  When I did a hard boot it asked for my root password.  I assumed it was the result of the sudo command in the script file.
So I just needed to remove it from the .password file.  I booted from a Ubuntu 14.x thumb drive and removed the line from the .profile.  I think I am on Ubuntu 22.x
When I rebooted I get :
error: symbol `grub_file_filters' not found.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>

My boot drive is (hd0,msdos1) What do I need to do?

I tried "grub rescue> set root=(hd0,msdos1)/boot",  "grub rescue> insmod linux" and got "error: symbol `grub_calloc' not found.  Any ideas?
